# How to take mix data type in a list as user input in python 3?

Tags: python

```
a = input()
a = list(a)
```

then

```
>>> hello 1 5
['h','e','l','l','o',' ','1',' ','5']
```

How can I get  the output like

```
a = ['hello', 1, 5]
```

Comment: The answers below are helpful, but I think it's important that you understand that `input()` is always going to return a string for you, and that casting a string to a list is going to give you a character array like in your original question. There's no automatic way for python to just figure out what datatypes you have in your input, you're going to have to write some code to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` to split it into words, and then use `isdigit` and cast for any sub strings that are integers.

```
[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in a.split()]
```

Comment: won't work very good with floats or negative numbers though ;)

Comment: @DeepSpace - True, but I'm sure once the op has given this a go they'll consider updating this community wiki answer ;)